# Same result obtained on mocking same method inside a loop with different conditions

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to test a method number of times with different conditions. The conditions are dependent on values returned from methods invoked internally from the tested method. However I am receiving the same result again and again.

```
@Test
    public void testMethod() {
        try {
            TestBn testBn = getTestBn();
            when(mockDatabase.getDBConnection()).thenReturn(conn);
            PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mockDatabase).closeDBConnection();

            List<String> accListForCurrentYear = new ArrayList<>();
            accListForCurrentYear.add("Test String 1");
            accListForCurrentYear.add("Test String 2");
            accListForCurrentYear.add("Test String 3");
            accListForCurrentYear.add("Test String 4");

            for (String accStr : accListForCurrentYear)
            {
                AccountTypeBn acctypeDto = new AccountTypeBn();
                acctypeDto.setAccountTypes(accStr);
                when(mockOnlineClaimDAO.getAccountType(Mockito.any(Connection.class), Mockito.anyString(),
                        Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Date.class),
                        Mockito.any(Date.class))).thenReturn(acctypeDto);

                UserDetailsBn usrDtlsBn = getCommonUserDetails();
                TestBn newTestBn =  mockClaimBO.validateInitialClaimDtls(usrDtlsBn, TestBn); //Method to be tested
                for (ResultBn resultBn : newTestBn.getAccbnList())
                {
                    System.out.println("Property1 : "+resultBn.getProperty1());
                    System.out.println("Property2 : "+resultBn.getProperty2());
                    System.out.println("Property3 : "+resultBn.getProperty3());
                    System.out.println("Property4 : "+resultBn.getProperty4());
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("### testMethod ### Failed with following error: " + getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }
```

I am receiving the same output (properties stored after the first iteration).

Answer (score 1):

I think your function `mockOnlineClaimDAO.getAccountType` always returns the same  object.

The best solution is to define a unique matcher using `eq` to your `mockOnlineClaimDAO.getAccountType` function, as now you only use wildcard matchers. Example:

```
when(mockOnlineClaimDAO.getAccountType(Mockito.any(Connection.class), Mockito.eq(accStr),...`
```

Another option you have is to use consecutive stubbing. You then have to add multiple `thenReturn` statements:

```
when(mockOnlineClaimDAO.getAccountType(Mockito.any(Connection.class), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(Date.class)))
.thenReturn(new AccountTypeBn("Test String 1"))
.thenReturn(new AccountTypeBn("Test String 2"))
.thenReturn(new AccountTypeBn("Test String 3"))
.thenReturn(new AccountTypeBn("Test String 4"));
```

or alternatively pass all return values in 1 `thenReturn` block:

```
when(mockOnlineClaimDAO.getAccountType(Mockito.any(Connection.class), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(Date.class)))
.thenReturn(new AccountTypeBn("Test String 1"), new AccountTypeBn("Test String 2"), new AccountTypeBn("Test String 3"));
```

With each call to the stubbed function, the next object will be returned.

Comment: This does not work. I have tried using consecutive stubbing. `mockOnlineClaimDAO.getAccountType` is not invoked multiple times. Is there any other way apart from writing as many test cases for as many strings based on which AccountTypeBn object is created.

Comment: @arnab testing multiple test cases in 1 unit test is considered bad practice as all will fail when 1 case fails. Best to bite the sour apple and write multiple test cases